# What type of question doesn't use inversion? Embedded? Confirmatory?

Tags: grammar, word-order, questions

What do we call this type of question in English "So Andrew **was using** Michael to smuggle shitty bullets into Mexico?" as opposed to "**Was Andrew using** Michael to smuggle shitty bullets into Mexico?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This paper seems to call these *confirmation questions*:
[Asking Questions...](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/asking-questions-using-meaningful-structures-to-imply-ignorance/)

> For example, if you are told that in many parts of the world people eat insects, you might utter **"People eat insects?"** to elicit further information (a mere "Yes!" wouldn't suffice), enough to entitle you to assert it yourself. If you don't believe your ears when told of a certain football result, you might ask **"Appalachian State beat Michigan?"** to make sure that you heard it right. Or you could ask "Appalachian State beat who?" to get confirmation that it was not Millington but powerhouse Michigan that lowly Appalachian State miraculously defeated. Fiengo observes that whereas standard, open questions take an inverted or "deformed" form (in English and many other languages anyway), **confirmation questions** do not.

[emphasis added]

Your example starts with **so**, but I don't think that changes it much, except to suggest that something said previously led to the conclusion that you're asking for confirmation of.